# How do I allow iOS users to upload a document via an html input field on my website?

Tags: php, html, ios, wordpress, upload

I have a contact form 7 plugin on my wordpress site, I want to allow users to upload a CV. On iOS devices though users are only given options to take a photo or upload a photo. On android and any other device I'm able to choose file.

Is there any way to get around this iOS functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible within Safari. Safari, and most iOS apps, operate within a sandbox, meaning they can't access other data and cannot read files outside their scope. I think iOS only supports [photo uploads.](http://ipadinsight.com/ios-6/ios-6-and-ipad-image-uploads-working-nicely/)

Comment: Yea, I've seen only ios 9+ enables you to choose a file :(

Comment: It looks like you could make your own iPhone app to allow uploads.